# I want to take a single value from one function and use it in another function - codeigniter/php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to take a value from a query in one function and use it for multiplication within another function.

Here i have a function producing the number 3:

```
function insert() {
$siteid = 1;
$field = 3;
$time = "2011-10-11 15:04:56";
$this->db->select('Offset_value', 1)
     ->from('offset')
     ->where('siteid', $siteid)
     ->where('Offset_field', $field)
     ->where('time <', $time);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo $row['Offset_value'];
    }
return $query; 

}
```

At the moment this is just set to display the number 3 but i need that value to be stored in a variable of some sort and load it into this function:

```
function get_sap_estimate() {
    $kwp = 5;
    $direction = 34;
    $tilt = 60;
    $month = 4;
    $sap_shadingid = 2;

    $this->db->select('derating_factor')
         ->from('sap_shading')
         ->where('id', $sap_shadingid);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    $query = $query[0];
    $dr = $query['derating_factor'];

    $this->db->select("kwh * $dr * $kwp AS kwhdata")
         ->from('expected_kwh')
         ->where('direction', $direction)
         ->where('tilt', $tilt)
         ->where('month', $month);
    $query2 = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query2;

}
```

Can this be done and how??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function A(){
   return "value"; 
}


functionB(){
   var value = A(); // here is your array 
   var value_you_need = value[0]['Offset_value']; 
}
```

Comment: when i return the value i'm producing 'array' as the result instead of the number

Comment: Look at my edit, you can just grab the value you need from the returning array.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both in the same class (read: model file) write

```
var $_var;
```

before any methods are made. Then inside one of your methods type

```
$this->_var = $stuff;
```

to give this var a value. Then to use that value type

```
$new_stuff = $this->_var;
```

If they're not in the same class, you could try calling the first method inside of the second.